# BSON Unterminated string literal error when inserting entries

Tags: mongodb, bson

I am trying to insert the following entries into my MongoDb database. However, upon inserting my entries I have come up with the following error:

2020-11-22T15:00:17.456+1100 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @(shellhelp1):1:24
error2:SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @(shellhelp1):1:24

Here is my query:

```
db.game.insert(

{"_id":ObjectId(),

 "TEAM":{"ID":"name",

         "name":"Averagers United",

         "city":"Average Town",

         "homeGround":"Average Stadium",

     "hasPlayer": [{"firstName":"Jon",

                        "lastName":"Average",

                        "position":"Main",

                        "number":"001"},

                       {"firstName":"Alan",

                        "lastName":"Normal",

                        "position":"Support",

                        "number":"222"}],

         "gamesPlayed": [1,2]

    }

})



db.game.insert(

{"_id":ObjectId(),

 "GAME":{"ID":"gameNumber",

     "gameNumber":1,

     "venue":"Average Stadium",

     "referee":"A-aron",

     "homeTeamName":"Averagers United",

     "homeTeamScore":3,

     "awayTeamName":"Low Achievers FC",

     "awayTeamScore":1

    }

})



db.game.insert(

{"_id":ObjectId(),

 "GAME":{"ID":"gameNumber",

     "gameNumber":2,

     "venue":"Stadium De Elite",

     "referee":"Jayqualine",

     "homeTeamName":"Elite United",

     "homeTeamScore":2,

     "awayTeamName":"Averagers United",

     "awayTeamScore":1

    }

})



db.game.insert(

{"_id":"Forgetten United",

 "TEAM":{"ID":"name",

         "name":"Forgotten United",

         "city":"Forgettable Town",

         "homeGround":"Forgotten Stadium",

     "hasPlayer": [{"firstName":"Frank",

                        "lastName":"Forgetful",

                        "position":"Main",

                        "number":"011"},

                       {"firstName":"Lennon",

                        "lastName":"Amnesiac",

                        "position":"Support",

                        "number":"145"}],

         "gamesPlayed": [3,4]

    }

})



db.game.insert(

{"_id":ObjectId(),

 "GAME":{"ID":"gameNumber",

     "gameNumber":3,

     "venue":"Forgotten Stadium",

     "referee":"Alberto",

     "homeTeamName":"Forgotten United",

     "homeTeamScore":2,

     "awayTeamName":"Low Achievers FC",

     "awayTeamScore":1

    }

})



db.game.insert(

{"_id":ObjectId(),

 "GAME":{"ID":"gameNumber",

     "gameNumber":4,

     "venue":"Stadium De Elite",

     "referee":"A-aron",

     "homeTeamName":"Elite United",

     "homeTeamScore":5,

     "awayTeamName":"Forgotten United",

     "awayTeamScore":1

    }

})



db.game.find().pretty();
```

Any help in finding the error is appreciated as this is the first time I have encountered an issue as such.

Comment: Are you really inserting `ObjectId()` that's not the way

Comment: I have changed it already to include the necessary object ID. I have also fixed the issue that I was experiencing above. Thx for responding though.

Comment: The issue was due to the fact that I wrote my query on microsoft word first before porting it over to my VM. Once I made the changes to the objectId as well as rewrote it in my VM, the issue was fixed.